# iPhone - How can i change the language of UIAddressBook to german?

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, localization

i'm using the UIAddressBook interface to create a new Contact in my App. The problem is, that if the iPhone / Touch / Simulator is in German the UI is Englisch,

has someone an idea?

Greetings Fil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that your app is properly localized, ie that you have localized en.lproj, de.lproj etc files. The contact picker will only show up in the languages that your app is localized to

Answer (score 0):

ok got it, this works ... i just made the MainWindow.xib localized.

is there a way just to tell the app, that she is localized without changing the e.g. MainWindow.xib

(the problem now is that i have to change too MainWindow.xib's when i have changes)